# gvim: change the default working directory

Tags: vim

when I open gvim using `Alt+F2` it takes as its default working directory my home folder.

How can I change the working folder after or while running gvim? can i pass that folder as a parameter when open gvim?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use a shortcut.

The simplest way, though, would be to

```
:edit $MYVIMRC
```

append a line

```
cd /home/user/my/work/dir
```

save (optionally execute `:w|source %` to immediately reload)

---

### Inside vim

use

```
:pwd
:cd some/other/dir
```

To view/change current working directory.

Use e.g.

```
:cd %:h
```

to change to the directory containing the file loaded in the active window.
If you need/want to do this often, consider just setting **['autochdir'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autochdir%27)**

```
:se autochdir
```

From the docs:

> ```
> When on, Vim will change the current working directory
> whenever you open a file, switch buffers, delete a
> buffer or open/close a window.  It will change to the
> directory containing the file which was opened or
> selected.  This option is provided for backward
> compatibility with the Vim released with Sun ONE
> Studio 4 Enterprise Edition.
> ```
>
> **Note:** When this option is on some plugins may not work.

Comment: I've been using this `cd other\file\path` in my vimrc for over a year now, but it led to a bug two days ago when using `gvimdiff`. See my post here https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/27060/20016 .

Comment: @IDG I have never required to change work directories since I started using sessions (best with Tim Pope's [Obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession))). I agree now that it's probably not worth the side effects of putting it in vimrc

Comment: Interesting! I stopped using Vim's built in sessions and rolled my own version using vimscipt+python because---as it says at [Obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession)---vim sessions can do wonky stuff because it saves maps and options. I may check out Obsession later, so thanks for mentioning it. Tim Pope is my hero. (:

Answer (score 12):

<s>You can pass an a folder to `gvim` (when you have NERDTree then it will be a file tree)</s> You can `cd` before start to begin in directory you want or use `:cd <path>` command to change current working directory, which can be passed to `-c` flag when running Vim:

```
$ [g]vim -c 'cd <path>'
```

You can also check current dir using `:pwd` command.

Comment: You're right I missed that part. Adding a missing tidbit to my own answer then :)

Comment: @Hauleth thanks, but I'm using FuzzyFinder and changing the working directory just using `cd:` doesnt make the autocompletion of FF working corretly..I mean, it just doesn't autocomplete..

Answer (score 6):

You can change the working directory with the `:cd` command. You can also pass this in a command-line option like this:

```
vim -c "cd wherever"
```

If you like the working directory to always be the file you're currently editing you can use the `set autochdir` option. Put that in your ~/.vimrc or see `:help autochdir`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but I started using [CDargs](http://www.skamphausen.de/cgi-bin/ska/CDargs) which is a bash tool to mark certain directories as bookmarks, then use `cdb` and press tab to list all the bookmarked directories.
There is a vim plugin that interacts with the settingsfile of this tool: [vim-cdargs](https://github.com/gaffneyc/vim-cdargs).
This combo works really nice for me to switch between projects.
Or after opening gvim to go quickly to some bookmarked folder, then use Ctrl-p plugin to quickly find the file I want to edit.

extra hint: I don't even want to type :Cdb so I abbreviated c to expand to :Cdb by adding this to my vimrc:
`cnoreabbrev c Cdb`
after which typing `:c` followed by a space, will expand into `:Cdb`.

EDIT: I now use [vim-startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify) which provides a start page for vim that shows the most recent used files. And with the option `let g:startify_change_to_vcs_root = 1` it will change the working directory to the outermost vcs root folder of the file you opened. Which is almost always what I want.
Furthemore, I created my own 'plugin' with some key mappings that will switch to the closest or furthest directory, in the path of the current buffer, containing a .git directory or file. In order to easily switch between searching for files in the current git submodule or in the overal supermodule.

Also I switched to fzf with [fzf-vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) instead of Ctrl-p, which works significantly faster and is more highly configurable.

---

Comment: why are you using the term 'folder' a late windows term, while speaking of bash. In *nix OSs and DOS  the word directory is used.  The word 'folder' is used by johnny come lately windows users

Comment: Thx for the info, didn't know this, I adjusted my answer and will never use the term 'folder' again ;)